# inject method to retrieve data from hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having trouble getting the method below in my user model to handle a hash ('auth') I'm getting from LinkedIn for user signin:

```
def self.deep_get auth, *fields
    auth.inject(auth) { |acc, e| acc[e] if acc }
end
```

I call the 'deep_get' method later in my user model as I create a user using omniauth/linkedin gem. However, it's returning nil values for the provider/uid/headline/email user fields that I know are not nil.

I included first_name and last_name fields as an example because this approach is working (not returning nil values), but (as I realize) bad style/exception handling. Any ideas as to why my deep_get inject method isn't working to retrieve the data in the hash as I'd like it to?

```
def self.create_from_omniauth(auth)

      create! do |user|

        # i'd like to retrieve user information from linkedin per the following with my inject method, but i am getting nil values when i should be getting data.

        # :provider and :uid are on the same branch level of data. first_name,last_name,email,etc. are on a branch just below called 'info' 

        user.provider = deep_get(auth, :provider)
        user.uid = deep_get(auth, :uid)
        user.headline = deep_get(auth, :info, :headline)
        user.email = deep_get(auth, :info, :email)

        # the below is working but i know pokemon exception handling is not good style. 

        begin
          user.first_name = auth["info"]["first_name"]
        rescue
        end

        begin
          user.last_name = auth["info"]["last_name"]
        rescue
        end
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
def deep_find(obj,key)
  if obj.respond_to?(:key?) && obj.key?(key)
     obj[key]
  elsif obj.respond_to?(:each)
     r = nil
     obj.find{ |*a| r=deep_find(a.last,key) }
     r
  end
end
or try this
class Hash
  def deep_fetch(key, default = nil)
    default = yield if block_given?
    (deep_find(key) or default) or nil
  end

  def deep_find(key)
    if key?(key)
      self[key]
    else  
      self.values.inject(nil) do |memo, v|             
        memo = v.deep_find(key) if v.respond_to?(:deep_find)       
        memo unless memo.nil?  
      end 
    end     
  end
end
```